# Summing value of each thread in the array and returning total value of all threads

Tags: java, multithreading

```
    int num_threads = 4;
            List<List<Integer>> seq;
            //created four new magnetization thread
            Magnetizationthread myt[] = new Magnetizationthread[num_threads];
            //go through the newlycreated thread  
for (int i = 0; i < myt.length; ++i) {
            //initializes the thread one by one
            myt[i] = new Magnetizationthread(i + 1);
            myt[i].start();
            //store the sequences genarted in a List
            seq = myt[i].generateSequences(2);
            for (i = 0; i < seq.size(); i++) {
                //gets the sequence generated by the threads
                System.out.println(seq.get(i) + "configuration " + i);
            }
```

** Not sure how to get the sum of individual thread and then get their total from an array

```
        I have generated the threads for each configuration and tried adding sum method but getting type mismatch 
        expect to show sum of each configuration thread and their total sum in the end
[-1, -1]configuration 0
[-1, 1]configuration 1
[1, -1]configuration 2
[1, 1]configuration 3
all threads spawned
thread #, sum = 0   0
```

Someone suggested storing return values in an array then assigning Id to each thread  and using the Id as index of array not sure how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you
**

```
class Magnetizationthread extends Thread {
public int sum;
public int len = 0;

Magnetizationthread(int n) {
    len = n;
}


// Computes the total sum of all elements of the given array.
    public static int sum(int a[]) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            result += a[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

public List<List<Integer>> generateSequences(int seq_size) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    // for our recursion base case
    if (seq_size == 1) {
        List<Integer> new_seq_1 = new ArrayList<>(); // add -1 once
        new_seq_1.add(-1);
        List<Integer> new_seq_2 = new ArrayList<>(); // add 1 once
        new_seq_2.add(1);
        result.add(new_seq_1);
        result.add(new_seq_2);
        return result;
    }

    List<List<Integer>> sub_ans = generateSequences(seq_size - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < sub_ans.size(); ++i) {
        List<Integer> new_seq_1 = new ArrayList<>(sub_ans.get(i)); // add -1 once
        new_seq_1.add(-1);
        List<Integer> new_seq_2 = new ArrayList<>(sub_ans.get(i)); // add 1 once
        new_seq_2.add(1);
        result.add(new_seq_1);
        result.add(new_seq_2);
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: What's the definition of a Magnetizationthread?

Comment: @FedericoCiuffardi Magnteizationthread extends thread and has method to generatesequences. basically you can generate array of size 1 with [-1] or [1 ] for sequence 1 and for 2 of size 2 with array of [-1, -1], [-1, 1], ...

Comment: @FedericoCiuffardi                                                                                         
 class Magnetizationthread extends Thread {
 public int sum;
 public int len = 0;

 Magnetizationthread(int n) {
  len = n;
 }


 // Computes the total sum of all elements of the given array.
  public static int sum(int a[]) {
   int result = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    result += a[i];
   }
   return result;
  }

 

}

Comment: can you edit your question so it includes the Magnetizationthread definition?

Comment: @FedericoCiuffardi you mean in the code portion up top?

Comment: No, the definition of Magnetizationthread that you commented previously

Comment: @DIGITALTECHNOLOGY Also - can you add definition of `generateSequences` method inside Magnetizationthread?

Comment: @Zgurski  private static List<List<Integer>> generateSequences(int seq_size){
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        // for our recursion base case
        if(seq_size == 1){
            List<Integer> new_seq_1 = new ArrayList<>(); // add -1 once 
            new_seq_1.add(-1);
            List<Integer> new_seq_2 = new ArrayList<>(); // add 1 once
            new_seq_2.add(1);
            result.add(new_seq_1);
            result.add(new_seq_2);
            return result;
        }